# RamdaJS Typescript pipe definition with types

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I am trying to us the RamdaJs with TypeScript like

```
const x = R.uniq( R.map( R.assoc( 'x', '' ), 
                R.filter<Service, Service[]>( serviceFilter, allServices ) ) 
) as Service[];
```

I want the I did not need to use `as Service[]` at the end but using types it should have `Service[]` as response.

And this all in a pipe function.